# PIL crop image python

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

This is my code:

```
from PIL import Image

image = Image.open('/root/Downloads/crew.jpg')

Left = int(input('Left : '))
Right = int(input('Right : '))
Upper = int(input('Upper : '))
Lower = int(input('Lower : '))

values = Left, Right, Upper, Lower
crop_image = image.crop(values)
crop_image.show()
```

But when I execute this code it shows this error:

```
    fh = fp.fileno()
    AttributeError: '_idat' object has no attribute 'fileno'
```

Please help me to solve this error.

Comment: Try to save the cropped image first, then show it. `crop_image.save('cropped.jpg')`

Comment: Where do you assign a value to `fp`?

Comment: It is the error message occurred in pillow ImageFont lib.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The points for the cropped image should be given as a tuple.

```
from PIL import Image

image = Image.open('xxxx.jpg')

Left = int(input('Left : '))
Right = int(input('Right : '))
Upper = int(input('Upper : '))
Lower = int(input('Lower : '))

values = (Left, Right, Upper, Lower)
crop_image = image.crop(values)
crop_image.show()
```